# prevent keyup when input focus

Tags: jquery, input, keyup

I intent to trigger something with spacebar key, but spacebar should be prevent trigger when input is focus.

I'm trying with this way, but it doesnt work well
is there any suggestion how to do it right.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('blur', function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 32){
        alert("pressed!");
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label> Name</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <br />
  <label>Pass</label>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: To clarify the question: do you want to disable the "triggering something with spacebar" while the input is focused, and when the input loses focus, "trigger something" again?

Comment: I mean, It can be trigger anytime, but when input setfocus trigger is disable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detach the handler with `.off()` while input has focus:

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            alert("pressed!");
        }
    });
    $('input').on('focus', function() {
        $(document).off('keyup');
    });
    $('input').on('blur', function() {
        $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 32){
                alert("pressed!");
            }
        });
    });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label> Name</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <br />
  <label>Pass</label>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: I see, I didnt notice that event can be stop with .off(), it work good, thank you for suggestion.